# Mocking repository / filling db BEFORE container start for app-startup integration test

Tags: spring-boot

I'd like to write integration test to verify proper function of `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` annnotated method, but I need to setup the data to be found by some repository. The `@SQL` is executed only before `@Test` method, ie. after the `ApplicationReadyEvent` was processed., `@MockBean` followed by `Mockito.when` in `@Before` method is the same, it's reached only after `@SpringBootTest` finished initialization, namely after `ApplicationReadyEvent` was processed.

I also tried to provide `@TestConfiguration` with bean defined as:

```
@Bean
SomeRepository someRepository() {
    SomeRepository someRepository = Mockito.mock(SomeRepository.class);

    Mockito.when(someRepository.findById("value")).thenReturn(...);
    return someRepository;
}
```

but this is somewhat insufficient, as the `@SpringBootTest` still finds actual implementation of this repository (even if I add `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`) and run crashes with this conflict.

How can I prepare the mocked repository or actual data in test db for this scenario?

Comment: TBH the easiest way would be to load the data by other means, e.g. liquibase or `data.sql`. You could also simply unit-test the listener, I suppose you can be fairly certain that the `@EventListener` annotation is working correctly. Alternatively, just add `@Primary` to your mock bean definition, but keep in mind it will remain mocked in other tests as well. Perhaps this problem could be solved using a spy wrapping the original bean, it depends on your requirements

Comment: sadly in this usecase there is lot of ApplicationContext manipulation, so it's not feasible for unit testing. `@Primary` does not help. Liquibase would work using some context, but I did not set it up for project testing yet, and that would be overkill. Data.sql—no idea how to do that per usecase."spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true" fix the issues with startup, but original and not mocked bean is used. I have no idea what can be done in this case: I want all as in production, except 2 beans: TaskScheduler and one repository which has to be mocked before container start. No idea.